# Prove that $L=K[x]/\langle m(x)\rangle$ is an algebraic extension of $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $m(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$. How can I prove that $$L=\frac{K[x]}{\langle m(x)\rangle}$$ is:

1. A vector space of dimension $n$,
2. An algebraic extension of $K$?

Edit: I'm going to post what I've come up with so far. Please point out any errors within my proof.

Let $\varphi:K[x]\rightarrow A,\varphi(p(x))=p(a),a\in A$

We can, by the 1st Isomorphism Theorem, say that

$$\frac{K[x]}{\langle m(x)\rangle}\simeq K[a]$$
because $ker(\varphi)=\langle m(x)\rangle$.

Due to the Division Algorithm, we can say that $$p(x)=q(x)m(x)+r(x)$$ which means that every $p(a)$ can be written as $$p(a)=r_0+r_1a+...+r_{n-1}a^{n-1}$$

As such, if we take $B=\{1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}\}$ we can see that $B$ generates $K[a]$ (which is isomorphic to $\frac{K[x]}{\langle m(x)\rangle}$) over $K$, which has dimension $n$.

Comment: These are very basic theorems in any abstract algebra book that covers fields and galois theory.  I'd wager the proofs are on the relevant wiki pages.  Did you look there?

Comment: *Hints*: $x\in L$ is algebraic over $K$ and generates $L$ over $K$. $\{1,x,\dots,x^{n-1}\}$ is a basis for $L$ as a $K$-vector space. (Actually, the latter (finite dimensionality of $L$ over $K$) implies that $L$ is an algebraic extension of $K$.)

Comment: @GregoryGrant I did, and didn't find any sadly. My abstract algebra book doesn't provide the proof, instead leaving it as an exercise to the reader. I wasn't able to prove it and hence asked here.

Comment: You should now show what you have tried so far to avoid your question being closed.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Working on some proof right now. I'm a little out of it since I had to miss part of the semester so it's taking more than I'd like for it to, but I'm on it.

Comment: @HolyThunder Alright. Post it as soon as you are finished. And if you have any questions on the process you may ask in the comments to my answer. Think first before asking though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Show that as $m (x)$ is irreducible then through the homomorphism $\varphi : K[x] \to \Omega$ defined as $\varphi(f)(x) = f(a)$ as $a \in \Omega$ is such that $m (a) = 0$ you have that $$\frac{K[x]}{\langle m(x) \rangle} \simeq K[a]$$

(Use the First Isomorphism Theorem)

- Show that for any $f(x) \in K[x]$, $f(a)$ can be written uniquely as

$$f(a) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 a + \ldots + a_n a^n$$

where $\alpha_i \in K$.

(Use the Division Algorithm)

- Notice that if $[K[a] : K] = n < \infty$ then $1, a, \dots, a^n$ are L.D. And also that $$\{1, a, \ldots, a^{n-1}\}$$

is a basis of $K[a]$ over $K$.

**Note:** By definition $K[a] = \{f(a) ; f(x) \in K[x]\}$. And is possible to show that it is a integral domain such that $$K \subseteq K[a] \subseteq L$$
where $L \supseteq K$ is an extension over $K$.

Comment: To use the First Isomorphism Theorem shouldn't $\langle m(x)\rangle=ker(\varphi)$?

Comment: That's right...

Comment: So I just need to prove that $im(\varphi)=K[a]$?

Comment: Yes. Think first, and then you ask, remember?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm very behind on this class because I missed half the semester so I seem to be having trouble with the most basic things.

Comment: All you need is to read through your old notes and take the track back again. Make sure you have your book and notes near you to tackle this exercise.

Comment: I'm going to have to cut this short due to having exams in 6 hours, but I'll pick it up again after the exam tomorrow. Thanks a lot for the help though, I'll mark your answer and come back tomorrow. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.